# Thunderbird runs with an empty profile after I used sudo

Tags: sudo, thunderbird

I once ran `thunderbird` with the `sudo` command and now when I run it (with or without `sudo`) it does not load my default profile. The files of my default profile are still in the `.thunderbird` directory.

Answer (score 2):

You likely messed the permissions of the folders that is uses such as the cache, and it's configuration settings.

Try running the following to get back ownership of all files in your home directory, provided you are logged in as the user who cannot open Thunderbird:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```

Make sure you're in your home directory when you do this!

If you are running as another user in a multi-user environment, you must replace `$USER` with the user's name.

Ensure in the future that you do not run it as root again.  Similar issues can happen with other software as well. It is safer to use `sudo` with the `-H` flag : `sudo -H (executable)` so that the software runs in `root`'s home directory instead of your own user's home folder.

Comment: I fixed your `chown` command.

Comment: @ByteCommander Re-edited.  That's fine if you only have one user, but not in a multi-user environment where you're fixing another account's permissions.  It's always best for one-liner fixes to explicitly specify the username instead of relying on variables.

Comment: Okay, the question did not give me any reason to think that he might want to run that from a second account, but additional clarification can never hurt.

Comment: Agreed @ByteCommander.  I try to never assume these things, mostly because I administer a large organisation :)  In fact, I would probably set the owner in a script by cycling through each /home folder and check the owner with `ls -ld ./ | awk '{print $3}'` and use that to `chown` back to the user, but I don't want to go too crazy with my answer :)

Comment: Didn't work. I don't know how to use the -p option with thunderbid exactly.

Comment: @Reza try running `thunderbird --ProfileManager` to see if you can select a profile.

Comment: I did and there is only a default profile which is empty.

Comment: @reza At this point you may need to cut your losses and uninstall/reinstall it.  It'll probably be easier in the long run.  Just make sure to delete the thunderbird folders `~/.thunderbird` as well as the Thunderbird folders in `.cache` and `.config`.